# aluminum anodizing power supply schmetic

Tags: power-supply, power

It has been a long time since I played with the electrons. In my day filament transformers were common and power supply design included the number and type of tubes being used.LOL
Anyway I need to build a power supply to provide current to anodize the parts for an AR-15 rifle. The average part is 7075-T6 AL and has about 24 sq in of surface. 
I have been using a battery charger that provides 12VDC at about 6amps but it overloads and requires restarting frequently which requires constant attention and provides an uneven surface.
I have a transformer that will give me 17v or 20v with plenty of current capability along with 4 ea MJ11032 Darlington transistors on a big heat sink that I salvaged from an old battery backup unit.
Problem is that I don’t know how to design a working power supply with these components. I have or can get any other needed parts caps resistors etc.

Will somebody be kind enough to give me a simple schematic??

Comment: "Plenty of current" is not exactly an engineering specification. Can you be more specific? You basically need a rectifier, and maybe you can add a current limiter using those transistors.

Comment: A guess from basic chemistry and physics (I have *no* anodizing experience), I'd guess you should use a constant-current supply for anodizing to get consistency. The anodizing process has to do with the motion of charges and if you want to use a simple timer for working out consistent results you should want a constant current supply. Also, aluminum starts out conductive but anodizing builds towards very high resistance as it proceeds. With constant voltage then too much current early will cause burning and too little in the end will prevent the coating from getting thick enough.

Comment: @DaveTweed The current will be above an amp, I'm sure, but below 10 amps for projects this small. My guess would be the OP needs to have a settable constant current supply with a variable current setting and a compliance voltage of perhaps as little 30 V but probably it might be better if that compliance voltage could reach 40 V or a little more. Just bits of chem and physics and a small background involving corundum and sapphire. Probably should buy it, though. Ah. I found a reference suggesting 12-15 amps per sq ft of surface. Compliance of 30 V is about right. So 2 A here, I think.

Comment: @jonk: But we've already established that 6A is not enough...

Comment: @DaveTweed Yes. And after checking I find that there is also Type II and Type III. (I was looking just thinking from basic chemistry in my head and apparently the reference I found is "type I" -- oh, well.)  Type II uses 30 amps per sq ft and 24 volts of compliance. Type III uses 40 amps per sq ft at 75 volts of compliance.

Comment: Gunner, after doing some background searches I suspect you are using sulfuric acid anodizing and probably want something called "MIL-A-8625", which is Type III, Class 2 Anodizing for Gun & Rifle Components." Is that your goal?

Comment: Gunner, also, if Type III, it appears you should target up to a 75 V compliance and perhaps as much as 10 A constant current capability. That's a deliverable 750 watts into a load. Not a small power supply, at all. You could look for something with half the compliance voltage and accept what that gives you. But are still around 400 W. And that still is not a small constant current supply design. Either will require careful and knowledgeable work from you to build. Are their kit designs, perhaps? Is it cost keeping you from buying one?

Comment: I think that you have got a good understanding of the problem, jonk. I am using a H2S04 solution and AL for the anode and cathode so the load resistance does change. As I finish one and start another the anode resistance continues to increase but the new cathode starts lower and increases as the coating increases. I don't know the spec on the capability of the xformer but from the "looks" I guess that I can drive it at 15A on the 17V winding. I don't have a spec sheet. Type III, Class 2 would be fantastic but this is a hobby project no need for MIL SPEC. I just want it to work and look nice.

Comment: @Gunner43 Nothing I have read suggests that 17V is enough compliance voltage. Near the end of the process, you need voltage. I'm ignorant about this topic and just learning on the fly as I go, but I'd say you want to be *able* to reach at least twice that voltage. Maybe more. I am beginning to see why the current needs to be closer to 10-15 A. But I think the design should be constant current because of the difficulties involved with being forced to constantly change voltage if it is a voltage type power supply. Sounds like a SMAW (stick) welder, almost. Big. Not cheap. Buy used?

Comment: i have completed one with the 12v battery charger and other than the fact that it took constant attention it did OK.I was hoping that if I built a power supply that did not shut off on me I could continue without the babysitting. I just do not know the circuit for the darlington transistors and other parts I have on hand.

Comment: Perhaps I gave too much detail. All that I wanted was a schematic using the MJ11032 Darlington transistors as a rectifier to give me a DC output with a 17 -20v AC input.

Comment: You can't easily use (Darlington) transistors as rectifiers, it requires a fairly complex control circuit. Better to just invest in some beefy stud-mounted rectifier diodes.

Comment: If you just need 12VDC at a bunch of amperes, a PC power supply is a pretty good choice. You may have to put a load on the 5V supply (of the order of a 12V automotive brake lamp on the 5V) and short a couple pins together to get it to start. Many can supply tens of amperes on the 12V bus- for example a  Corsair CX650 is rated at 54A. *However* your 12V charger may actually be putting out 16 or 17V near the end with a light load.

Comment: Thanks guys.. This is the info that I was looking for. I have a box full (Not an engineering quantity lol) of the old 1N4001 diodes that I can hook up in parallel to make an ugly but functional bridge rectifier. the MJ's or a couple of PF55N06 MOSFET's would be pretty but too complicated. Thanks for the help and advice. I'll go away for now but may look into the PC supply as an option. I hadn't thought about them and they are pretty cheap.